# What is the difference between a cookie and a session in django?

Tags: django, session, cookies

I think they are same thing but my boss say that is not right. Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A cookie is something that sits on the client's browser and is merely a reference to a `Session` which is, by default, stored in your database.

The cookie stores a random ID and doesn't store any data itself. The session uses the value in the cookie to determine which `Session` from the database belongs to the current browser.

This is very different from directly writing information on the cookie.

Example:

```
httpresponse.set_cookie('logged_in_status', 'True')
# terrible idea: this cookie data is editable and lives on your client's computer


request.session['logged_in_status'] = True
# good idea: this data is not accessible from outside. It's in your database.
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353703/session-cookie-some-misunderstandings)

Comment: What's the difference between `SessionStorage` & `CookieStorage` here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#configuring-the-message-engine -- Aren't they alternate ways to save data. However you say that cookie doesn't store data itself.

Comment: @buffer, with SessionStorage, the default, the cookie contains an ID to a data store in the database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `FallbackStorage` is the default storage class which uses `CookieStorage`. This stores data in a cookie until size permits before switching to `SessionStorage`. The latter maybe how you are describing i.e. cookie stores ID to session.

Comment: @buffer, FallbackStorage is for the messages framework. The default session engine is `django.contrib.session.s.backends.db` which works as described above. Please ignore my comment on `SessionStorage` - not sure what that is.

Comment: I'm confused. Even this page says cookie is storing data (not just session key). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/ says `When using cookies-based sessions django.contrib.sessions can be removed from INSTALLED_APPS setting because data is loaded from the key itself and not from the database, so there is no need for the creation and usage of django.contrib.sessions.models.Session table`

Comment: @buffer yes, if you enable that cookie session storage scheme. By default, django uses `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db` - database backed sessions.
If you instead use `django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`, django will store data in the cookies and not use a database session table. For the purposes of this question, it is assumed that you are not using `signed_cookies`, as a majority use the default system.

Answer (score 12):

A cookie is not a Django, or Python specific technology.  A cookie is a way of storing a small bit of state in your client's browser.  It's used to supplement (or hack around, depending on your point of view) HTTP, which is a stateless protocol.  There are all sorts of limitations here, other domains cant read your cookies, you can only store a a few k of data (just how much depends on the browser!), etc, etc.

A cookie can be used to store a session key.  A session is a collection of user state that's stored server side.  The session key gets passed back to the server, which allows you to look up that session's state.  Most web frameworks (not just Django) will have some sort of session concept built in.  This lets you add server-side state to an HTTP conversation.

Answer (score 0):

To complement '**Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita's answer**'

with cookies You can set any information on client browser
not just id (session id),

cookies are **limited** (size limited to kb), **less secure** and **less flexible** compared to sessions.

django sessions are based on cookies, django uses a cookie to save **session id** on client

sessions are **not limited** to data size (because they are saved on db of server), **more secure** and **more flexible**.